# How to create a new table and then join the table with itself in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am taking a SQL class in school and the question asks us to

"Write a query that finds, for each customer X, another customer Y who has rented movies from the same actor. Find all such pairs of Customers (X, Y) and against each pair, the overlapping number of actors. The query should thus have three columns. Order the results by the number of overlapping actors"

I know that I need to create a new table and then join that table with itself but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Where in the question does it say anything about a new table? It's more likely it wants you to perform `JOIN`s and/or `CROSS APPLY`s on existing tables.

Comment: So I tried doing it by creating a view but it keeps giving me a runtime error so then thats why I think I need to create a new table and then join it to itself

Comment: Are you working with an existing database for the context of these assignments, or are you expected to create the tables mentioned in the question locally? This seems more like a question for your instructor. We can't debug your local setup for you; the best anyone could do is help you write a `SELECT` given tables that are already there (but then you would at least need to supply the definition of those tables and sample contents).

Comment: I am using the existing SAKILA database

Comment: You are asked to write a query. A query result is a table. But we would't call this creating a table. We only use this term when we actually crate a table in the database with the `CREATE TABLE` statement. You merely want to select from the existing table and join this to itself on the condition "different customer, same actor". Then you aggregate this so as to get one result row per joined customer pair and count how many actors they share.